# Passing a SELECTED VALUE from a normal HTML5 SELECT list to MVC controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have seen many examples of passing select list data generated from a ViewModel down to an MVC controller but I have not see an on how to pass the selected value from a normal `<select>` HTML5 tag. For example, in my View I have :

```
    <select id="Type">
        <option value="Game">Game</option>
        <option value="Collection">Collection</option>
        <option value="Cinema">Cinema</option>
        <option value="Book">Book</option>
    </select>
```

How do I pass the selected value from that select list down to my controller so I can then add it into my EF model?

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddSection(Section NewSection, HttpPostedFile LogoFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (LogoFile != null && LogoFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if (LogoFile.ContentType == "image/png")
                    {
                        string FileName = NewSection.RouteName + "Logo";
                        NewSection.LogoFileID = FileUploadHelper.UploadSiteImage("Logos", FileName, LogoFile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("File Type", "Logo Files must be PNG files.");
                        return View(NewSection);
                    }
                }

                using (db)
                {
                    db.Sections.Add(NewSection);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                ModelState.AddModelError("Processing Error", "There was a problem processing the new section, please try again later.");
                return View(NewSection);
            }
        }
        return View(NewSection);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Section
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int16 ID { get; set; }

    public Int64? LogoFileID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(250), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string RouteName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Synopsis { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
    public virtual File Logo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the select's `name` attribute to the same value as the name of the parameter expected by the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string type)
{
    //do work
}
```

html:

```
<select id="Type" name="Type">
    options...
</select>
```

If you are posting a complex model like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    //do work
}
```

select's `name` attribute should be equal to the model's property name ("Type" as well).

If you don't want to follow this convention for some reason, you can also access the posted values from controller using the `Request.Form` property.

You also need to change action's signature to

```
public ActionResult AddSection(Section NewSection, HttpPostedFileBase LogoFile)
```

to bind the file.

Comment: Type is the name of the parameter that is being expected but I get the error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` if I try to bind directly to the EF model, if I just try to pass in a set of parameters the Selected Value is not picked up.

Comment: In your example the select list does not have `name` attribute, it should be present to successfully bind the model. Does your model actually have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: I have no idea what a parameterless constructor is and the HTML5 spec says we are not to use the name attribute on tags anymore, so does MVC5 break the HTML5 standard?

Comment: MVC model binder is pure server-side, it has nothing to do with html standards. It's task is to build the model from request data (present in `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString`), it doesn't know how exactly these values were posted(html form, desktop client, etc...). AFAIK, html5 specification refers `<a>`, not `<input>` tag's `name` attribute, cause you *are* allowed to have multiple inputs with the same `name` (for example, radio buttons), but you cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: So I added `name="Type"` and I still get the paramterless error

Comment: This is a server-side error, post your controller and model definitions to investigate it.

Comment: Change the second parameter type to `HttpPostedFileBase`

Comment: That fixed it, if you ppost it up as an answer I will mark it so

Comment: Thank you very much , when i put name="" it's work fine